# Android splash screen animation not working

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen

When my splash screen finishes (2 secs) and when moving to my main activity, I want this action with alpha animation. Everything works, except the animation...

Here's my code. Is there something wrong with it? (I have a text and an image for splash screen)

**MainActivity.java** (haven't really touched anything here)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        int delay = 2000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        }, delay);
    }
    public void onBackPressed(){}
}
```

**fade_in.xml**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

**fade_out.xml**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.id11201478.WhatIf" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activty_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/splashLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="What If?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/appName" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appImage"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: i tried your code as it and the animation work with me fine , could you post the xml files and manifest file also ??

Comment: Yeah I added them, could it be something with API? I'm using API 19...

Comment: still work with me ,  could  you tell me the android version that you test on it

Comment: It is API version 19.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving your code

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

to `MainActivity`. So it becomes something like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    } 
}
```

Comment: tried it, but still goes to MainActivity without animation :(

Comment: Can you try moving the `overridePendingTransition` code before `setContentView` ?